# Can one achieve local style from an external .css file?

Tags: css, ajax, html

I suppose most are aware that the HTML5 specification has introduced scoped:

```
<style scoped="scoped">
```

Allowing locally scoped style elements that exist outside the page `<head>` section.

Rather than embedded style, our preference would be to reference local style from external CSS files, and we were hoping to do it as follows:

```
<link href="somelocalstylefile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" scoped="scoped">
```

But localized `<link>` functionality is not part of the HTML5 spec.

Does anyone know of another HTML5 compliant way we can locally apply style from an external CSS file?

Comment: The attribute is named [`scoped`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-style-scoped), not `scope`. And it's a boolean one, so use `scoped` or `scoped="scoped"`, but not `scoped="true"`.

Comment: What is your question? This does not look like a question, rather a rant about some desired feature.

Comment: @oriol - thanks have corrected (please feel free to correct any other typos you see)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I have reworded in a way that hopefully you find more accessible. Please do reply if you have an answer!

Comment: _“Does anyone know of a way I can achieve the above in HTML5 - ie. local scoped style from an external file?”_ – AJAX/JSONP your file’s content, and put it into a scoped `style` element yourself …?

Comment: @CBroe - thanks, my aim is to deliver the scoped style only once, thereafter simply reference it locally for each subsequent AJAX call (ie. identical to the page level <head> style/link distinction but localised to the AJAX delivered content).  Is this possible with your method? and if so could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: A request made via AJAX differs little from any other request, so caching would happen the same way.

Comment: @CBroe - One very good reason for using the page header level "link" statement in preference to the "style" statement in a non-ajax environment, is that the external CSS file referenced by link is cached locally automatically, even if page content changes on page reload. The same does not hold true for page level "style" element content. I see that HTML5 now offers "local style", but I would like to find out if there is an equivalent "local link" ability so that we can take advantage of the same CSS caching locally as full pages benefit from currently. Do you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`@import` rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) inside a `style` element to refer to an external style sheet:

```
 <style scoped>
 @import "somelocalstylefile.css";
 </style>
```

Beware that support to the [`scoped` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) is still limited. Worse still, browsers that do not support it apply the rules inside the `style` element to the document as a whole, as if it were a normal `style` element in the `head` part.

Comment: In principle this looks excellent! Just a confirmation if you don't mind: Is the above approach "legal" i.t.o. the HTML5 standard? (as an aside, while I know that Firefox does support scoped, I'm not really concerned whether other browsers do - and am working on the assumption that it will be supported by mainstream browsers at some point in the not too distant future :o) )

Comment: It’s legal: HTML5 does not restrict the content of a style sheet in a `style` element, whether the `scoped` attribute is present or not. And CSS has had `@import` for a long time.

Comment: Thanks Jukka, we have tested and your answer works. Unfortunately using this method the returned content displays un-styled for a brief period before the styling is applied. I have read up a bit and it seems that this is a known issue with @import. There are workarounds suggested but they don't apply for our situation unfortunately ...so we are sticking with scoped style (without the @import) for small amounts of styling and page global link method when larger volumes are required.